# Array: out of the index/boundaries

Tags: c

In the following code, I've assigned values to an array elements which are out of the array boundaries, In *Linux* environment in the *CLI* the code give me the error message: `array index 5 is past the end of the array which contains 5 elements`.

But while debugging on *IDE* codeblocks -compiler cannot find this bug- so is there any explanation?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main ()
{
   int array[5],i;
   for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
      array[i] = i+1; 
   }
   array[5] = 666;

   for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
      printf("array[%d]=%d\n", i, array[i]);
   } 
   printf("array[5]=%d\n", array[5]);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The use of indicies outside the array's boundaries is [undefined behaviour](https://www.google.pl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%20undefined%20behavior). You cannot except any IDE do anything.

Comment: What is the compiler of codeblocs?

Comment: Think about the implications of **undefined** _behaviour_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeblocks, like most IDEs, does not contain a compiler and won't generate warnings like this by itself. Instead it calls a command-line compiler like gcc, and displays to you the errors and warnings the compiler returns.

You should check what compiler is called, with what compiler options, in Codeblocks/project settings.

gcc should generate an *"array subscript is above array bounds"* warning for your code, but only with the `-Wall` and `-O2` options (or equivalent).

Optimization (`-O2`) is often not enabled for debugging, which could be an explanation why you don't get the warning *while debugging*.

Answer (score 0):

> When you access an array index, C and C++ don't do bound checking. The values you get when you read are just what happens to exist on the *stack* at this particular place. They are completely undefined.

The difference between the two compilers is possibly due to the fact that one of those is a newer version including some array bound checking.